# How remove color bottom nav menu

Tags: android, android-studio

I can remove color from item. Select item have purple color and unselect have grey. I need when select item don’t have color only color png and unselect grey.[image]

Answer (score 0):

As I tried to understand you want to paint the button when it is clicked.
So you can use the onClick event to change color with setBackgroundColor(Your color) button property.

I think you can create a method that set de background of button to purple on the button clicked and grey to others, call it in each button click event.

PseudoCode:

```
private void paintButton(Button b){
 for(Button but : ListOfYourButtons.items){
  if(but.equals(b))
   b.setbackgroundColor(Color.Purple);
  else
  but.setBackgroundColor(Color.grey);       
}
```

Comment: No. I want the button with the image to have the native color and not the changed one.

Comment: Try this [color-list-resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource)